# Toggling on/off Markers in Google Maps API v3

Tags: api, google-maps, dictionary, toggle, google-maps-markers

I'm having trouble getting the setMap(null); function that everyone seems to be recommending to work.

I believe it may be a problem with the way I've implemented the markers.

If someone could take a look and let me know if you see something wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

LINK: http://www.dougglover.com/samples/UOITMap/v2/

Please Note: Old link above, doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The basic problem is that if you want this to work you've got to make up your mind about what the `markersTest` object is supposed to hold.  You can't seem to decide whether the elements in `markersTest` should be markers or should be arrays that tell you about where markers are going to be placed.

Quoting from your javascript file, here are the two functions that get executed when you check/clear the checkbox:

```
15  function addTestMarkers(){
16      for(var i in markersTest) {
17          var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markersTest[i][1], markersTest[i][2]);
18          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
19              position: location,
20              map: map
21          });
22      }
23  }
24  
25  // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
26  function clearOverlays() {
27      if (markersTest) {
28          for (i in markersTest) {
29              markersTest[i].setMap(null);
30          }
31      }
32  }
```

For `addTestMarkers` to work, the `markersTest` object needs to hold descriptions of where the markers should go.  For `clearOverlays` to work, the `markersTest` object needs to hold markers.

Here's my suggestion: change the `markersTest` object as you set it up at the top of the javascript file to `markerDestinations`, and at the top of the javascript file have `markersTest` initialized with:

```
markersTest = {};
```

Then, modify `addTestMarkers` to:

```
function addTestMarkers() {
    for(var i in markerDestinations) {
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markersDestinations[i][1], markersDestinations[i][2]);
        markersTest[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

The key change is to make `addTestMarkers` actually put the markers into the `markersTest` object.

Comment: Ok, so instead of initializing an array like it is an object, use my array to create the properties of an object to be used for display purposes, if I take your meaning correctly.

I'll take your advice and look into it.

Truth be told, I only really started even LOOKING at the API this week(Monday), and feel that despite some hard walls, I'm making due pretty alright with the newer version, as opposed to opting for the currently more complete version 2.

Anywho.  Thanks again, I'll look into changing the map as you've suggested.

Answer (score 15):

**Do not use setMap(null)** for toggling markers on a map! Therefore the API offers the setVisible method, what is the appropriate method for that task.